# Open Data Standard for Stack Exchange?

Tags: standards

In light of the fact that this site is about open data, is Stack Exchange based upon any open data standard(s)?

I converted the group welcome statement to open, standard, machine-readable StratML format at http://xml.fido.gov/stratml/drybridge/index.htm#ODSE

Comment: This would be a great question for the SE team.

Comment: agree with @FreshPrinceOfSO or it could be at least be moved to the meta section of this site.

Comment: @magdmartin If the question is otherwise on-topic here, it's fine to keep it on the main site even though it mentions Stack Exchange. (Unfortunately, I don't immediately have an answer to it.)

Comment: Which open data standards do you have in mind? Could you provide a few examples?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much about open data standards, but as far as I'm aware, no. Stack Exchange itself isn't based on any particular standard.

We provide all publicly-accessible data via an XML-based [data dump, but I believe its schema is simply mimicking the database schema we also expose via the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

Every Stack Exchange site comes with a "Creative Commons with Attribution and Share Alike" statement. I would consider that an Open Data Standard.

You are allowed to:

> - to Share - to copy, distribute and transmit the work
> - to Remix — to adapt the work
> - to make commercial use of the work

(Source: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)